# Where to store mock files in a flutter project?

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, flutter-test, flutter-mockito

Is there any best practice for where to store mock files in Flutter?
Particularly, the auto-generated mock files, since I'm using `@generateMocks` annotation from [Mockito](https://pub.dev/packages/mockito) package.

Should I, for example, create a package dedicated for storing **all project's mocks**? or keep each mock in **the test package that depend on it**? or are there other approaches? pro and cons?

I found some related questions for other frameworks, and although it seems like a language-agnostic issue, I'm interested in knowing whether there are any recommendations for Flutter specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I keep the mocks with the test files that need them. So you'd have a `random_test.dart` and `random_test.mocks.dart` with the `@GenerateMocks` attribute in the `random_test.dart` file.

**Pros**

- Unlikely to conflict with others during development unless you're working in the same area
- Easier to know *where* the mocks for specific tests are
- Easier to customize mocks for different test cases

**Cons**

- Likely to have repetitive generated code
- Longer `build_runner` calls, due to the repetitive generation
- More files in the project

  - This can be somewhat mitigated by generating the files when needed instead of storing them in the repo, though that adds to the impact of the longer `build_runner` calls

All in all, I don't mind the cons when put up against the easier dev cycle of just keeping the mocks with the specific tests that need them. Unless you're generating an *enormous* amount of mocks for each test, the extra time and repetitive generation aren't overwhelming IMO.

Comment: Thank you for the well structured answer @pdblasi ! 
I agree with pros/cons you listed, and also decided to go with this approach. 
Moreover, it turned out that Mockito doesn't make it easy to choose otherwise anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can save your mock files for testing. If some people work on that project with you. They can just pull the project and run testing. But it depends on your team's culture. I share my experience but not the best practice for you.

Comment: Just to clarify, my question is WHERE to store the mock files, not whether to store them or not.